# Finding big Oh involving real number multiplication

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have the following homework question:

An -degree polynomial () is an equation of the form:

[image: equation]

Where  is a real number and each  is a real constant, with  ≠ 0. Describe a simple (^2)-time method for computing () for a particular value of . Justify the runtime.

So my question is: is it even possible to guarantee O(n^2) runtime since ai can be any real number, and as it approaches infinity so does the runtime.

Here is what I have typed out so far:

"Since the fastest know algorithm for multiplication (Harvey-Hoeven algorithm) takes Θ(nlogn) time (where n is the number of digits in each of the numbers being multiplied), and since ai can be any real number, there is no way to guarantee O(n^2) time. This is because if any one of the constants ai are greater than, for example, n^2 digits long then that single multiplication would take at least (nlogn)^2 time."

if this is not true, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Does this help you? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/horners-method-polynomial-evaluation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with many complexity theory problems that "runtime" is measured in (usually unspecified) abstract units, which may not correspond with wall-time on a real computer. Here I guess the person asking the question meant runtime as "arithmetic operations". Although it's not clear, because there's no obvious algorithm that runs in O(n^2) arithmetic operations that's not also in o(n^2).

Your answer is correct, if you assume the "bit complexity model", although usually in that case the "n" would be the size of the input and not the limit of summation, and the details of how real numbers are represented would become important.

Answer (score 1):

There can be 2 cases:

**Case 1:** If n approaches to infinity, then your point of view is correct.

**Case 2:** If n is real number not approaching infinity, the computation will involve `n` number of additions operations( a0 + a1 + a2 + a3 + .... + an).

Assuming the maximum length of some integer, `ai` is equal to some constant `m`, then the overall time complexity would be `O(n * m)`.